# Python Gurobi: Cannot add constraints to the model

Tags: python, gurobi, mixed-integer-programming

can somebody correct me what's wrong in this code?.

I am trying to write the constraint as shown in the image.

[image]

But raising TypeError

```
<ipython-input-189-be5360af354c> in <module>()
      1 balance_energy = m.addConstrs((quicksum(electricity_demand[t, u, app, task] * x[t, u, app, task] + gas_demand[t, u, app, task] * y[t, u, app, task]+ hotwater_demand[t, u, app, task] * z[t, u, app, task] for t in time_slots) ==
      2               (task_electricity_req[app][task] + task_gas_req[app][task] + task_hotwater_req[app][task])
----> 3             for u in users for app in appliances for task in task_appliances[app]), name = "balance_energy")
      4 

model.pxi in gurobipy.Model.addConstrs (../../src/python/gurobipy.c:89287)()

<ipython-input-189-be5360af354c> in <genexpr>(.0)
      1 balance_energy = m.addConstrs((quicksum(electricity_demand[t, u, app, task] * x[t, u, app, task] + gas_demand[t, u, app, task] * y[t, u, app, task]+ hotwater_demand[t, u, app, task] * z[t, u, app, task] for t in time_slots) ==
      2               (task_electricity_req[app][task] + task_gas_req[app][task] + task_hotwater_req[app][task])
----> 3             for u in users for app in appliances for task in task_appliances[app]), name = "balance_energy")
      4 

TypeError: must be str, not int
```

I have tried this so far

```
balance_energy = m.addConstrs((quicksum(
  electricity_demand[t, u, app, task] * x[t, u, app, task]
  + gas_demand[t, u, app, task] * y[t, u, app, task]
  + hotwater_demand[t, u, app, task] * z[t, u, app, task]
  for t in time_slots) ==
  (task_electricity_req[app][task]
  + task_gas_req[app][task]
  + task_hotwater_req[app][task])      
  for u in users for app in appliances for task in task_appliances[app]),
  name = "balance_energy")
```

Here 
**Continous Varables**

```
electricity_demand[t, u, app, task]
gas_demand[t, u, app, task]
hotwater_demand[t, u, app, task]
```

**Binary variables**

```
x[t, u, app, task]
y[t, u, app, task]
z[t, u, app, task]
```

**Parameters: Dictionary which contains Integer value**

```
task_electricity_req[app][task] 
task_gas_req[app][task] 
task_hotwater_req[app][task]
```

Solution:
Doing the below trick solved my Problem.

```
 balance_energy = m.addConstrs((quicksum(electricity_demand[t, u, app, task] * x[t, u, app, task] 
                                         + gas_demand[t, u, app, task] * y[t, u, app, task]
                                         + hotwater_demand[t, u, app, task] * z[t, u, app, task] for t in time_slots) ==
               (float(task_electricity_req[app][task]) + float(task_gas_req[app][task]) + float(task_hotwater_req[app][task]))      
             for u in users for app in appliances for task in task_appliances[app]), name = "balance_energy")
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you add full error?

Comment: @kurag, I have added the full error, please have a look.

Comment: My suggestions: look what returns at your "for" loops, try print them out of model. Or delete constraint, look if there is another error. Or delete some part of constraint to find exact error point.

Comment: Providing a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would increase your chances for getting an answer :).